# SQL Query to return count of rows until limit date

Tags: sql, math, count

I've got the following dataset

| customer | Inicial_date | Limit_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Phill | 2023-01-01 | 2023-06-01 |
| Jhon | 2023-03-01 | 2023-07-01 |
| Ellie | 2023-09-01 | 2023-10-01 |
| Mark | 2023-12-01 | 2024-03-01 |

I want to count the rows where the customers were between the inicial_date and limit_date by month.
I need to get on the result bellow.

| month | customerCount |
| --- | --- |
| 2023-01 | 1 |
| 2023-02 | 1 |
| 2023-03 | 2 |
| 2023-04 | 2 |
| 2023-05 | 2 |
| 2023-06 | 2 |
| 2023-07 | 1 |
| 2023-08 | 0 |
| 2023-09 | 1 |
| 2023-10 | 1 |
| 2023-11 | 0 |
| 2023-12 | 1 |
| 2024-01 | 1 |
| 2024-02 | 1 |
| 2024-03 | 1 |

Comment: first which mysql version d do you have? second have you da date table already created?

Comment: Are you using Databricks or MySQL? These are totally different platforms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering for databricks because it's easier.

If you want the inequalities to not be inclusive you can tweak that in the join. If you want a wider date range change the arguments to sequence().

```
%sql
with all_dates as (
  select explode(sequence(DATE'2023-01-01', DATE'2024-03-01', INTERVAL 1 DAY)) as day_sequence
)
select all_dates.day_sequence,
       count(yt.customer) as count_on_day
         -- assumes yt.customer will never be null in the original data.
  from all_dates 
  left join
       your_table yt
    on all_dates.day_sequence >= yt.initial_date
   and all_dates.day_sequence <= yt.limit_date
 group by
       all_dates.day_sequence
```

Comment: Wow dude! Worked perfectly!! Thank u!

Answer (score 0):

Using a recursive `cte` to build the month ranges:

```
with recursive cte(dt, cnt) as (
   select t.dt, (select sum(c1.inicial_date <= t.dt and t.dt <= c1.limit_date) 
      from customers c1) 
   from (select min(c.inicial_date) dt from customers c) t
   union all
   select c.dt + interval 1 month, (select sum(c1.inicial_date <= c.dt + interval 1 month 
         and c.dt + interval 1 month <= c1.limit_date) 
      from customers c1) 
   from cte c where c.dt < (select max(c1.limit_date) from customers c1)
)
select year(dt), month(dt), cnt from cte;
```

[See fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/p2w4hiKF).